# how to use setequal() to find unique vector pair?

Tags: r, function, set, unique

I have a simple data frame as the following:

```
    v1 <- c(1,2)
    v2 <- c(1,3)
    v3 <- c(2,1)
    df.test <- data.frame(rbind(v1,v2,v3))
    colnames(df.test) <- c('from', 'to')
```

I want to use a `for` loop to find & append all rows into a separate vector and then use `unique` or some `set` function to get the unique vector pair and store them into a new data frame. For now, I have:

```
    c <- c()

    for (row in 1:nrow(df.test)) {
        from <- df.test[row, "from"]
        to  <- df.test[row, "to"]
        new.row <- c(from, to)
        c <- c(c, new.row)

        # having trouble storing unique values here...


     }
```

Ideally, after taking only the unique value pairs, the new dataframe should look like this:[image]

Can anyone please help? Thank you!

Comment: If you sort every pair before rbind, you can simply use unique() around the data frame to remove duplicated pairs, e.g.  unique(rbind(sort(v1),sort(v2),sort(v3)))

Comment: thanks, but imagine there are hundreds of rows, then apply `sort()` to each of them will be somehow cumbersome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# sort rows
df.test <- t(apply(df.test, 1, function(x) sort(x, decreasing=F)))

# get unique rows
df.test <- unique(df.test)
print(df.test)
```

Comment: thank you, this is concise and useful!